# Our system detected a lock condition in our database

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.1

We are getting an issue with the database.

Below is the message we are getting from the server.

**Our system detected a lock condition in your database. Multiple queries were running too long. The queries were killed to maintain your site's availability. Below is a process list of running queries for your analysis.**

We are getting below log.

```
764607 user_3775zonjvaf 10-1-84-65.kubelet.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:38450  dbm2.3.1 Query 3 Sending data SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM sales_order_address 554545 0 
764608 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 89 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO search_query (store_id,query_text,popularity) VALUES ('1', 'other diesel duramax 3Fmanufacturer', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE popularity = popularity + 1 0 0
764610 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc: dbm2.3.1 Query 86 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO search_query (store_id,query_text,popularity) VALUES ('11', '23store menu', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE popularity = popularity + 1 0 0
764611 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 84 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (NULL, 'd82a1755183639f90d0c6d51838e0a97', '2019-07-28 02:00:30') 0 0
764612 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 82 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (NULL, '6bd54e0a314761c7bd896a875e5069f7', '2019-07-28 02:00:32') 0 0
764614 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 80 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (NULL, '1c70facf26d11c7d33ef9130ebc7be17', '2019-07-28 02:00:34') 0 0
764615 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 75 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (NULL, 'e3e6b77293b8a2ffab164f7920888985', '2019-07-28 02:00:39') 0 0
764616 user_3775zonjvaf 192-168-27-52.php-fpm.store-3775zonjvafwenb8.svc.cluster.loc:  dbm2.3.1 Query 50 Waiting for table level lock INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (NULL, '7c885091c2589782414c5f9c7000f1c3', '2019-07-28 02:01:04') 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to some cron running in the backend.
You can check from the database using **SHOW PROCESSLIST** command. It will give you the list of processes and you can kill them if they lead to deadlock.